# Flash player not working in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, flash-player

I am using linux ubuntu, and I cannot run any flash file. I need to know how to install flash player.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Using flash in your browser or do you want to open flash files? If you want to watch .flv movies use the vlc media player

Comment: Questions regarding Ubuntu are better suited for http://askubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you prefer to click or type do one of following things:

- find **Adobe Flash Plugin** in Ubuntu Software Center and click **Install**  - check [this post](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/09/install-adobe-flash-player-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat/) for a detailed explanation with screenshots
- run this command in terminal - `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree`